# A Probability Problem - At least one event happens!

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

I was given the following exercise:

"At the railway station in London there are three mailboxes: one is labelled as "City", another "Rest of the country" and the last "Abroad". John wants to send three postcards: one to London, another to Cambridge and the last to Rome. He randomly puts a postcard in each mailbox. What is the probability that at least one postcard is correctly mailed?"

I modelled the problem in this way: each letter is represented by a Bernoullian variable, i.e.
$$X_i=\begin{cases}1\;\;\;\;\; p=\frac{1}{3}\\ 0\;\;\;\;\; 1-p=\frac{2}{3}\end{cases}.$$
Then, let's call $X=X_1+X_2+X_3$ a Binomial variable. The probability that Jhon correctly sends at least one postcard should be:
$$\mathbb P\left(X\ge 1\right)=1-\mathbb P\left(X<1\right)=1-\mathbb P\left(X=0\right)=1-\left[\binom{3}{0}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^0\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^3\right]=\frac{19}{27}.$$
Unfortunately, the right answer is $\frac{2}{3}$. Can you help me finding out where I am making mistake?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your approach would be correct if John put each letter in a mailbox independently.  Here, though, we are told that he puts one in each mailbox.  Thus the placement of one affects the placement of the others.  Best to just write out the six possible placements.

Comment: And to spell the name John correctly.

Comment: Sorry for the typo!